# Calculating Hebrew date in Python

Tags: python, datetime, date, calendar, hebrew

I'd like to calculate Hebrew dates (primarily the current Hebrew date) in Python. Which library is mature, easy to use, and documented?  I note these. There may be others.

- Python Date Utilities Library as discussed [here](http://www.ziporah-greve.net/prog/jewish-python.html)
- [Calendrical](http://jacob.tardell.se/python/calendrical.html)
- [libhdate Python bindings](http://packages.ubunut.com/lucid/python/libhdate-python)
- [This](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/db-sig/1997-December/000361.html) informal code listing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python Date Utilities library (available on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythondateutil/)) seems to be fine to do what you want, for more specific usage with hebrew dates you could have a look [here](http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-python.html), there are a lot of examples with many code snippets that should fit your needs i think.

Comment: Also, look at Calendrical Calculations books.  Very, very helpful.  http://emr.cs.iit.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/second-edition/